# Is possible to write in Python script setup.py which is going to check if all required packages already installed - otherwise install them

Tags: python-2.7, distutils, setup.py

I am making Tornado application(new to Python and Tornado so maybe question is stupid), and I am using additional Python packages like lepl, sqlalchemy and so on. Is possible to write in Python script setup.py which is going to check if all those packages already installed - otherwise install them ? Or I need to do this in bash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), and *only specify* these requirements:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # ...
    setup_requires=['lepl', 'sqlalchemy', ...],
)
```

Then use a proper installing tool such as [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), [`easy_install`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) (comes with `setuptools`) or [`buildout`](http://www.buildout.org/) to manage installation of those dependencies.

By separating dependency management and installation, you have much better control over what gets installed when.

I can recommend you read the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) to learn more about packaging of python code and dependency management.